# .main not formatting correctly - Django

Tags: html, css

I have the following two files where home inherits from base.

base.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .sidenav {
            height:100%;
            width:160px;
            position: fixed;
            z-index:1;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            background-color:#111;
            overflow-x: :hidden;
            padding-top:20px;
        }
 
        .sidenav a {
            padding:6px 8px 6px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size:25px;
            color: #818181;
            display:block;
        }
 
        .sidenav a:hover{
            color:#f1f1f1;
        }   
        .main{
            margin-left:300px;
            padding: 0px 10px;
        }
 
    </style>
    <title>{% block title %}Brandon's Site{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <div class="sidenav">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
    </div>
 
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
 
</body>
</html>
```

home.html:

```
{%extends 'main/base.html' %}
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .main{
            margin-left:300px;
            padding: 0px 10px;
        }
 
    </style>
</head>
<div class = "main">
{% block content %}
Add New Plant
<form method = "post" action = "">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type = "submit", name = "save">Add New Plant</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
</div>

</html>
```

However, the form in home.html for some reason isn't recognizing the left margin and is stuck under the sidebar that I've created to the left. It ends up looking like this:

[image]

Why isn't it offset to the right like the CSS implies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all i think it is not a problem about django...
and you head tag in home.html is not in a `block` so that it will not be in the final html

Comment: You're right. I had to move the block content to contain everything and that fixed the problem! Much appreciated.